# Custom Post Type by user

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

I made a Custom Post Type for events that can be added in the admin by only certain groups of users, like a Secretary.

This Secretary can add some new events, but I want to display each user his own added events when logged in to his dashboard.

How would I approach this?

Comment: Hi Morgalis, welcome to WPSE! I've edited your post to remove the mention of the plugin you're using as it's technically off-topic here (all third-party plugins are) and could result in your question being voted for closure. The rest of your question, though, is completely on-topic. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what I have understood is you have a Custom Post type as event and user role like Secretary.

Now if a Secretary logged in , he can only be able to see his own events added, not the other one.

So if the above is correct so for that, we will use **pre_get_posts** filter

```
function wp_list_mine_posts( $wp_query_obj ) {
    // Front end, do nothing
    if( !is_admin() )
        return;

    global $current_user, $pagenow;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php
    if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') )
        return;

    // Not the correct screen, bail out
    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow )
        return;

    // Not the event post type, bail out
    if( 'event' != $wp_query_obj->query['post_type'] )
        return;

    // If the user is not administrator, filter the post listing
    if( ! current_user_can( 'delete_plugins' ) )
        $wp_query_obj->set( 'author', $current_user->ID );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wp_list_mine_posts' );
```

So for this, only administrator can see all the events added by all users.
And if Secretary logged in then he can only be able to see his own events added.

Comment: Thanks Aftab Alam , i tried your function and it is working like you expected too. So i made few account to test it. Admin can see all events added in Costum Post Type , an Secratary can see also all posts maded until he creates one of his own , then the others dissapear. So when an secratary doesnt have any custom post he can see also all the others but not edit them. So i made an first custom post with an new secretay user and the rest dissapeared , only his own was vissible but not editable. Thanks in advance

Comment: about the edit part is was role related. but as long an secretary doesnt made ever an post he can se them all.but not edit them. they dissapear after he made at least 1 post , from then only his post is visible.