# Add WordPress users to a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, users

I have created a custom post type called Groups. I would like to provide an option to add Users to these groups in the Group edit page. Any help would be appreciated thank you. 
P.S: I thought of using the Post-to-Post plugin but I am not sure if that would be the right solution.

Comment: please check this link i hope this working for you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232887/custom-post-type-by-user

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ACF plugin` for https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/.

Steps need to do:

1. Download and installed ACF plugin.
2. Click on `Custom Fields` link at the left side menu
3. Add custom field as:
   [image]
4. Select custom as and publish it:
   [image]
5. Now add this code in `functions.php` file as:

> ```
> function acf_load_color_field_choices( $field ) {    
>     // reset choices
>     $field['choices'] = array();
>   $blogusers = get_users();
>   $field['choices'][0] = "Select User";
>   foreach($blogusers as $user){
>             // append to choices
>             $field['choices'][ $user->ID ] = $user->display_name;
>     }
>     // return the field
>     return $field;    
> }
> add_filter('acf/load_field/name=select_user_for_post', 'acf_load_color_field_choices');
> ```

6. Now if you create `Groups` post you will see users list in a dropdown as:

[image]

Important details:

1. [get user list](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/)
2. [Dynamically populate a select field’s choices](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/)